# Gradle doesn't resolve plugin that exists in the place gradle is searching for it

Tags: gradle

I have a java project using gradle 7.3 for building.

I have these plugins in my plugins block in build.gradle:
plugins {
id "java"
id "checkstyle"
id "application"
id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "7.1.2"
id "com.google.osdetector" version "1.6.2"
id "org.openapi.generator" version "4.3.1"
id 'de.undercouch.download' version '4.1.1'
id 'org.owasp.dependencycheck' version '6.3.2'
}

I'm doing a "--refresh-dependencies" and it complains it cannot find a common plugin. I added the debug flag and I see it is looking at the Gradle Central Plugin repository, I see that the plugin is there:

But gradle complains it cannot find it:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.enterprise', version: '3.7', artifact: 'com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.7'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.7')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:221)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$resolvePluginRequests$3(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:147)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:207)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:201)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolvePluginRequests(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:145)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:88)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:117)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
```

As you can see in the error message, gradle is indeed looking at the Gradle Central Plugin Repository. But I certainly can see that [the plugin is there](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gradle.enterprise/3.7) in Gradle Central Plugin Repository. So why can't gradle find it?

As is often the case with software, the error message doesn't explain **why it can't find the plugin.** SSL error? server unavailable? I get nothing. How can I get more information? Are tricks to try to get this working?